# Como fazer pesquisas internas no site pelo google via javascript

Tags: javascript, google

Criei uma função javascript que faz buscas dentro do meu site com a API do google search, porem eu gostaria que a palavra que eu digitar apareça somente algo vinculado ao meu site, atualmente está trazendo resultados do google.

Código js:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var cx = 'minhachave';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:')
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Como fazer para buscar somente dentro do meu site?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o element `gcse:search` com o atributo `as_sitesearch`, por exemplo:

```
 <gcse:search as_sitesearch="www.site_do_arthur.com"></gcse:search>
```

Documentação: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

Comment: coloco isso onde no código? pq ja tentei aqui e nao funcionou nao, continua do mesmo jeito.

Comment: @ArthurMoraes aonde do teu HTML é populados os dados da busca?